# How to check that the entered input is an integer or not in java?

Tags: java

How to check in this code that the entered input is integer or not if not then ignore the non-integer values and display the rest numbers.

I have done the full coding but for checking the input is integer or not and then printing the value. How should I do it?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class ques2
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int i,j;
        System.out.print("how many number you want to enter= ");
        i=sc.nextInt();
        int input[]=new int[i];
        System.out.println("Numbers should be great then 3");
        for(j=0;j<i;j++)
        {
            input[j]=sc.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println("Number entered are:");
        for(j=0;j < i;j++)
        {
            System.out.println(input[j]);
        }  
        System.out.println("Odd numbers are:");
        for(j=0;j < i;j++)
        {
            if(input[j] % 2 != 0)
            {
               System.out.println(input[j]); 
            }     
        }
        System.out.println("Palindrome numbers are:");
        for(j=0;j < i;j++)
        {
            int rev=0,n,num;
            n=input[j];
            while(input[j] > 0)
            {
                num=input[j] % 10;
                rev=num+(rev*10);
                input[j]=input[j]/10;
            }
            if(n == rev)
            {
                System.out.println(n);
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a helper function:

```
  public static boolean checkMe(String s) {
    boolean amIValid = false;
      try {
       Integer.parseInt(s);
    // s is a valid integer!
    amIValid = true;
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    //not an integer but you could continue with the rest numbers
    }
    return invalid;
    }
```

Comment: You could probably improve this answer by looking at what op has posted and trying to apply your fix to their code. eg. they are using nextInt.

Answer (score 0):

You can check it by comparing the ASCII value whether it lies between 91 to 100.
If yes then it will be an Integer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `String` in lieu of `int`. Then, you can go ahead with again `int` using `Integer.parseInt(x)` because it's already been verified as being valid integer after `do-while`

```
String num;
String regex = "[0-9]+";  // to check the string only is made up of digits

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

do {
    System.out.println("Please input an integer");
    num = input.next();
} while (!num.matches(regex));

int validNumber = Integer.parseInt(num);
/* .
   .
   .  *\
```

Answer (score 0):

You're already using `sc.nextIn()` which internally perform a regex-check as in @snr's post and a `Integer.parseInt` as in charly1212's post.

The only thing you should add is wrap it in a

```
try {
  int i = sc.nextInt();
} catch(InputMismatchException e) {
  //skip or repeat?
}
```

To deal with all cases, where the input is not an int (which includes values > Integer.MAX_VALUE and < Integer.MIN_VALUE)

The solution could look like this method, encapsulating all the input reading

```
private static int[] readNumbers() {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    int i = -1;
    while(i < 0){
        try {
            System.out.print("how many number you want to enter? ");
            i=sc.nextInt();
        } catch (InputMismatchException e){
            System.out.println(sc.next() + " is not a number, try again");
        }
    }

    List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
    System.out.println("Numbers should be greater then 3");
    for(int j = 0; j < i; j++){
        try {
            numbers.add(sc.nextInt());
        } catch (InputMismatchException e){
            System.out.println("Skipping input " + sc.next());
        }
    }
    return numbers.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();
}

...

int input[] = readNumbers();
```

Please not, that the exception blocks invoke `sc.next()` to read the current line (which is not integer) and proceed with the next line (the new input), otherwise the scanner would not proceed its position.